# (require 'cl) is leading to error "Attempt to modify read-only object"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using Emacs 24.3.50.1 and upon startup, helm does a `(require 'cl)` which leads to this backtrace.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Attempt to modify read-only object" (macro . #[385 "\301\2031
  advice-add(dolist :around cl--wrap-in-nil-block)
  byte-code("\300\301\302\303#\210\300\304\302\303#\207" [advice-add dolist :around cl--wrap-in-nil-block dotimes] 4)
  require(cl)
  require(helm)
```

Here is the output of `report-emacs-bug`

```
In GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2)
 of 2013-10-08 on tbrannon0
Bzr revision: monnier@iro.umontreal.ca-20131008145718-cl3xxlfwlm1k2hs6
Windowing system distributor `The X.Org Foundation', version 11.0.11103000
System Description: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Configured using:
 `configure --with-x-toolkit=gtk3'

Important settings:
  value of $LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  locale-coding-system: utf-8-unix
  default enable-multibyte-characters: t

Major mode: Debugger

Minor modes in effect:
  flx-ido-mode: t
  ido-everywhere: t
  show-paren-mode: t
  global-auto-revert-mode: t
  tooltip-mode: t
  mouse-wheel-mode: t
  tool-bar-mode: t
  menu-bar-mode: t
  file-name-shadow-mode: t
  global-font-lock-mode: t
  font-lock-mode: t
  blink-cursor-mode: t
  auto-composition-mode: t
  auto-encryption-mode: t
  auto-compression-mode: t
  buffer-read-only: t
  line-number-mode: t
  transient-mark-mode: t

Recent input:
C-l C-l C-p C-x o C-x o <help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> 
C-n C-n C-n C-n C-n C-n C-e C-a C-p C-p C-e C-a <help-echo> 
<down-mouse-1> <mouse-1> <down-mouse-1> <mouse-1> <double-down-mouse-1> 
<double-mouse-1> <triple-down-mouse-1> <triple-mouse-1> 
<help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> 
<help-echo> <help-echo> <menu-bar> <edit> <copy> <help-echo> 
<help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> <help-echo> 
<down-mouse-1> <mouse-movement> <mouse-movement> <drag-mouse-1> 
<help-echo> <down-mouse-1> <mouse-1> ESC x e m c a 
s <backspace> <backspace> <backspace> a c s v <backspace> 
v <backspace> - v e <tab> <return> <down-mouse-1> <mouse-1> 
ESC x e m a c s - b u <tab> <backspace> <backspace> 
d e b <tab> C-g ESC x b u g <tab> <tab> C-g ESC x r 
e p o <tab> r <tab> <return>


Features:
(shadow sort mail-extr emacsbug message format-spec rfc822 mml mml-sec
mm-decode mm-bodies mm-encode mailabbrev gmm-utils mailheader sendmail
help-mode debug init-prodigy prodigy hl-line easymenu f dash s
init-flx-ido flx-ido flx ido init-load-packages finder-inf mail-utils
network-stream starttls url-http tls mail-parse rfc2231 rfc2047 rfc2045
ietf-drums url-gw url-cache url-auth url url-proxy url-privacy
url-expand url-methods url-history url-cookie url-domsuf url-util
mailcap cl-macs gv advice help-fns package init-standard-packages ffap
thingatpt url-parse auth-source eieio byte-opt bytecomp byte-compile
cconv eieio-core gnus-util mm-util mail-prsvr password-cache url-vars
init-dired init-shell comint ring edmacro kmacro cl-loaddefs cl-lib
shell-current-directory ansi-color init-uniquify uniquify paren
autorevert filenotify time-date tooltip ediff-hook vc-hooks
lisp-float-type mwheel x-win x-dnd tool-bar dnd fontset image regexp-opt
fringe tabulated-list newcomment lisp-mode prog-mode register page
menu-bar rfn-eshadow timer select scroll-bar mouse jit-lock font-lock
syntax facemenu font-core frame cham georgian utf-8-lang misc-lang
vietnamese tibetan thai tai-viet lao korean japanese hebrew greek
romanian slovak czech european ethiopic indian cyrillic chinese
case-table epa-hook jka-cmpr-hook help simple abbrev minibuffer nadvice
loaddefs button faces cus-face macroexp files text-properties overlay
sha1 md5 base64 format env code-pages mule custom widget
hashtable-print-readable backquote make-network-process dbusbind
gfilenotify dynamic-setting system-font-setting font-render-setting
move-toolbar gtk x-toolkit x multi-tty emacs)
```

Comment: Start `emacs -Q`, explicitly load Helm, and check if that error still occurs.

Comment: And make sure, that your Emacs trunk build is up to date.

Comment: Yeah, this problem did not occur when loading Helm after `emacs -Q`